# Undefined Method for Nil even after a conditional

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, eager-loading

I have a variable called `@events`, which is a collection of `Listings` `.where(category: 'Tickets')`. Events (`:events`) are `eager_loaded` from the `User` model. In my view I have:

```
<% for event in @events do %>
  <% if event.has_orders? %>
    ...
    <% orders.each do |order| %>
      <%= order.foo %>
    <% end %>
    ...
  <% else %>
    ...
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Everything works in development, but not in production. When I iterate through `@events` in my view, the conditional gets ignored and `<%= order.foo %>` throws `undefined method [foo] for nil class`. Is this happening because `:events` are `eager_loaded` (preloaded)? If so, what would be the optimal solution?

Comment: It raises an exception on `event.foo` but not `event.has_orders?`

Comment: @eirikir yep. `has_orders?` passes. I'm doing another iteration for `.orders.each` and that's when the exception gets thrown

Comment: but if `event` is `nil` it would raise it in either case... what's the method that's "undefined" in the error?

Comment: yes, my mistake. I should've mentioned another iteration. Edited the question.

Comment: how is `has_orders?` defined? what if you replace that with `event.orders.present?`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Everything works in development, but not in production

It sounds like your data changed.  What changed?  Check this out:

```
class Order
  def foo
    puts 'hello'
  end
end

order = Order.new
order.foo


orders = [
  nil,
  nil,
  nil,
]

orders.each do |order|
  order.foo
end

--output:--
hello
1.rb:18:in `block in <main>': undefined method `foo' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from 1.rb:17:in `each'
    from 1.rb:17:in `<main>'
```

The orders array exists, but the error is the same as yours.  In other words, your `Event` could pass the `has_orders?` test, but you could still get that error.  You need to figure out why the orders array for an Event is being populated with nil values.

To avoid the error, you *could* write:

```
  orders.each do |order|
    order.foo if order
  end
```

Comment: mmmaan, I kept checking for `has_orders?` in production, but never actually checked for `foo` which was `nil` for one of the orders. Thanks!